# Trying to get div on same line with <li> using flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to arrange an image next to some text. I was able to accomplish this with font awesome icons and text, but two images I was unable to get an icon for, so I am using images. I can't seem to get them side by side. What am I missing? Here is the code:

```
<ul className='lower-nav-ul'>
   <li className='lower-nav__link'>
     <FontAwesomeIcon
       icon={'question-circle'}
       className='question-circle'
     />
     Help
    </li>
    <li className='lower-nav__link'>
      <FontAwesomeIcon
        icon={'map-marker-alt'}
        className='map-marker-alt'
      />
      Where to Buy/Rent
     </li>
     <div>
      <img src={require('../images/safety-icon-light.png')} alt='safety-icon'className='safety-icon'/>
     </div>
     <li className='lower-nav__link-with-img'>Safety</li>
     <div>
       <img src={require('../images/en-flag-light.png')} alt='en-flag' className='en-flag'/>
     </div>
     <li className='lower-nav__link'>EN</li>
 </ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
.lower-nav__link {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.lower-nav-ul {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

I've tried so many different things and just took it all back to where it looks best. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

a div is not a valid child of a ul (only li’s can be children of ul’s). You need to put your content into an li and use display: flex on the li to space them. the display: flex styling only applies to the immediate children of the element it is applied to

Answer (score 0):

Flex property applying on a container element. In your case **li** so move your **div** inside the **li** .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the second `<li>` element closes too early. The `<div>` that contains the `<img>` is after the closing `</li>` tag, so the style rules that apply to both the `<ul>` and `<li>` will not apply to it. Does moving that `<div>` inside the `<li>` tags solve the issue?

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: Great — glad to hear!